# Regex Return Everything Except for Double Quotes

Tags: regex, splunk

I wonder whether someone could help me please.

I'm trying to extract the following information from the data set below:

1 A Street, A Town, GB

```
{"matchingDataset":{"surnames":[{"value":"Smith","verified":true}],"gender":{"value":"MALE","verified":true},"dateOfBirth":{"value":"1973-12-26","verified":true},"firstName":{"value":"John","verified":true},"addresses":[{"verified":true,"postCode":"AB1 1BC","lines":["1 A Street","A Town","GB"]}],"middleNames":{"value":"john","verified":true}},"hashedPid":"123","matchId":"_123","levelOfAssurance":"LEVEL_2"}
```

I've put together the following regex:

```
"\"lines\":\[\"(?<idaAddress>[^\]]+)"
```

The problem I have is that this returns:

1 A Street", "A Town", "GB

Could someone tell me please is there a way remove the double quotes from this.

Many thanks and kind regards

Chris

Comment: why wont you just rejex the result ? mean use rejex twice, im not familiar with splunk orelse i could show you how to do it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I dont really know how does this splunk thing work but you can do this by two stages:

1- Catch the quoted expression `"1 A Street", "A Town", "GB"` withe the following regex:

```
\"lines\":\[(?<idaAddress>[^\]]+)
```

2- Then catch the values between quotes inside the token using this regex:

```
\"(.*?)\"
```

---

I dont know what is the tagged programming language used for, but i assume that set of instructions would not differ much than this:

```
regex _raw="\"lines\":\[(?<idaAddress>[^\]]+)"
regex idaAddress="\"(.*?)\""
```

Answer (score 1):

In the regex I could see \" which splunk treat as " (use \ to suppress special meaning for ") so they are coming in output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what splunk is, but surely it must have some kind of JSON parsing library (if not a built-in function). That's generally a much better way of doing these things than regexes.

I'll answer your question more directly, but *only* in the interests of helping you to understand regexes. The capture group is `(?<idaAddress>[^\]]+)`. The `"` at the start of `"1 A Street"` matches a `\"` in the regex, so the capture group starts matching immediately after it. If you do this: `"\"lines\":\[(?<idaAddress>[^\]]+)"` then the `"` in the string will be matched as part of the `[^\]]+` part. Or in fact `"\"lines\":\[(?<idaAddress>\"[^\]]+)"` will also make the `"` match inside the capture group.

As for the end of the string, the only explanation I can think of is that the `"` at the end works just the same as `\"` (i.e. you don't actually need the `\`). So if you remove the closing `"` (or move it inside the capture group) then the ending `"` will be captured, as intended. But this is just an educated guess.

Comment: Using a json library++

Comment: http://answers.splunk.com/answers/148307/how-to-parse-and-extract-json-log-files-in-splunk.html for example

Comment: Hi @David Knipe, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. I'm relatively new to Splunk and so JSON is a little too advanced for me at the moment. I have tried adding the " to the capture group but unfortunately this doesn't work. Kind Regards. Chris